# GoogleApiClient is deprecated for use with location

Tags: java, android, google-api-client

So I'm new to android java and new to using google services integrating into my app, I followed a tutorial online to get user current location and displaying nearby places. However, it shows that GoogleApiClient has deprecated and I don't really know how to work around this given the documentation too of https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApi using GoogleApi based API.

I also don't understand this documentation too for accessing google APIs https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#java .My app can run but it doesn't display the map and show current location at all. This is my first question to stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated!

This is my code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private Marker currentUserLocationMarker;
    private static final int Request_User_Location_Code = 99;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private int ProximityRadius = 10000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            checkUserLocationPermission();
        }

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }



   

    private String getUrl(double latitude,double longitude, String nearbyPlace){
        StringBuilder googleURL = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googleURL.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googleURL.append("&radius=" + ProximityRadius);
        googleURL.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googleURL.append("&sensor=true");
        googleURL.append("&key=" + "YOUR_KEY_HERE");

        Log.d("GoogleMapsActivity", "url = " + googleURL.toString());

        return googleURL.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkUserLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, Request_User_Location_Code);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case Request_User_Location_Code:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        if (googleApiClient == null){
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        lastLocation = location;
        if (currentUserLocationMarker != null){
            currentUserLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("User Current Location");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

        currentUserLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(12));

        if (googleApiClient != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1100);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it has been replaced! 
 Now yo have to use GoogleSignInOptions for accessing any google API client**

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).build();
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, so);
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = mGoogleSignInClient.asGoogleApiClient();
```

Comment: After using the above solution how to use this googleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx).addApi(LocationServices.API)
.addConnectionCallbacks(object : GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {}
override fun onConnectionSuspended(i: Int) {
 googleApiClient!!.connect()
  }
})